# Question involving combinatorics in regular polygon

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose $A_1, A_2, \dots, A_{20}$ is a regular polygon.

How many non-isosceles (scalene) triangle can be formed whose vertices are among the vertices but whose sides are not the sides on the polygon?

Comment: Have you tried the analogous problem for $n$-gons with smaller $n$?

Comment: You could also fix one vertex $A_j$ and count how many such triangles have that vertex and two others. Then multiply by $20$ to account for all the possible choices of $A_j$, then divide by $3$ to correct for the fact that this method counts each such triangle three times.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the number of ways of choosing 3 out of the 20 vertices such that no 2 vertices chosen are adjacent.

Count the number of acceptable triangles possible with the first vertex. 
This is 2.15 + 16.14 (if the next chosen vertex is A3 or A19, they share a common adjacent vertex and hence the third vertex will have 15 possibilities. If not, it will have 14 possibilities).

What is uncounted now are the triangles not containing A1. 
The number of such triangles having A2 is 2.15 + 16.14.
 Of the triangles possible with A3, 15 are already counted(those also  having A1). Hence, 2.15 + 16.14 -15 more triangles are to be considered. 
Of the triangles possible with A4, 14+15 are already counted(those also having A1 and those also having A2). Hence, you have 2.15 + 16.14-29 more triangles.

Whlie counting in this way, when you come to the nth vertex(n lies between 3 and 20), (n-3)14 + 15 triangles are already counted containg that verex.

So, the number of triangles is 2.15 + 16.14 + 19(2.15 + 16.14) - 18(15) - 2023.

Answer (score 0):

We begin by determining the number of possible types of triangles. When $a$, $b$, $c$ are the three "side-lengths" in ascending order then we have
$$a=2+x,\quad b=3+x+y,\quad c=4+x+y+z$$
with integer $x$, $y$, $z\geq0$. As $a+b+c=20$ we have to count the solutions of
$$3x+2y+z=11\tag{1}$$
in nonnegative integers. Now $x=0$ and $z\geq0$ enforces $y\in[0..5]$, then $x=1$ enforces $y\in[0..4]$, then $x=2$ enforces $y\in[0..2]$, and finally $x=3$ enforces $y\in[0..1]$. It follows that there are $6+5+3+2=16$ admissible solutions of $(1)$, or $16$ types of admissible triangles.

For any such type one can choose $A$ in $20$ ways and then $B$ in $2$ ways, and as the three sides are of different lengths no triangle is counted twice in this way. It follows that there are $16\cdot20\cdot 2=640$ admissible triangles in all.